# Ocropus Engine on iPhone and/or Android

Tags: iphone, android, ios, ocr, tesseract

What is the best way to get ocropus running on iOS and/or android?

I'm interested in using [Ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) to digitize some content on mobile devices. I'm largely interested in using a trained 'language' model to make predictions on the device. Training will occur offline and off device. I know a few people have got tesserect running on mobile devices, but I'm unable to find much information on doing the same with Ocropus. I'd greatly appreciate a slice of your collective wisdom in an effort to avoid wasting days taking the wrong path.

Would it be easier to just prototype the algorithm using the scripts, then grab the specific c++ code of interest and include it directly in my application. Or best to compile as a static/dynamic library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better setting up a simple web service that uses Ocropus or any OCR library for that matter. Then have your smartphone application make requests to the web service. OCR is a CPU intensive process, so it's appropriate to move it off of the phone.

Comment: That's the solution I'm running with, as many of the commands are not pythonic, and iOS doesn't support python - its the only real option.